# Consequence of Darboux theorem for derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $f$ be differentiable on $(a,b)$, $c \in (a,b)$, then prove that there is a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset (a,b), x_n \neq c$ such that $f'(x_n)$ converges to $f'(c)$.

My attempt:

Darboux theorem says that $f'$ assumes every value between $f'(c-\frac{1}{n})$ and $f'(c)$ within the interval $(c-\frac{1}{n},c)$ after some stage (to make $c-\frac{1}{n} \in (a,b) $). Is it a good construction of such sequence or how can we prove the convergence?

Comment: Darboux theorem will give a construction, but the answer below is simpler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition

$$f'(c)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0 } \frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$$

Insert the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ instead of $h$ we have

$$f'(c) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(c+\frac{1}{n}) -f(c)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Using Lebesgue intermediate theorem, there exists $x_n\in (c,c+\frac{1}{n})$ with $f'(x_n)=\frac{f(c+\frac{1}{n}) -f(c)}{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Then $f'(x_n)\rightarrow f'(c)$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Since $f$is differential at $c$ we have the function

$g:(a,b) \to \mathbb R $  ,  defined as

$$
g(x) = 
\left\{  
\begin{array}{ll}  
          \frac {f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}  & \mbox{if } x \not = c
 \\\\   f'(c)  & \mbox{if } x = c
  \end{array}
 \right.
$$

is continuous.

Now apply **Mean-Value Theorem**(as you have $f$ differentiable on $(a,b)$) to get a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset (a,b)$ such that $x_n\to c$ and $f'(x_n)\to f'(c )$